Why is the configuration of SpringBoot reading incorrect?
I need to hide my IP address. I set this IP in the environment variable of Mac and refer to this IP address in yml, but I can't read the correct address. It seems that I have read the previous old address.



I want to get the right configuration.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as properly formatted text.

If you don't want to communicate via the internet, why do you have to set any IP address?

Well ... if the OP is going to talk to another computer using TCP/IP, etc an IP address is essential.  However, if it is a private IP address, nothing on the internet (i.e. beyond the private network that understands the private IP) would be able to connect to the OP's host.  So going to great lengths to keep a private IP address secret is ... largely pointless.  And if the IP address is public, bad actors doing port scanning will eventually find it anyway ... unless the OP firewalls it.  So again, secrecy buys you little if anything.

This is my Internet ip. I must ensure security problems as much as possible, even if I can't guarantee it 100%.

Try adding your environment variables in the same scope that runs your app, so in your case use Intellij as shown bellow:

